# How to access the hostname of the machine my Reactjs web application is running

Tags: c#, reactjs, frontend, backend, hostname

I need to access the hostname of the user's computer, I believe it's not possible to do that, but the client insists and as I don't know everything I use the help of you dear colleagues, please help me, the project is done in FrontEnd Reactjs - Backend C#

Access the hostname of the user's machine

Comment: I don't think it's possible with regular Web APIs. What would you need it for?

Answer (score 0):

By hostname you mean the IP of the user, right?

I am not sure this is the best approach but you can just get the user IP address and store it inside a state and then pass it wherever you want.

Here is an example:

```
npm install axios
```

```
const [userIP, setIP] = React.useState("");
```

This will help you get the data you want (IPv4 and more):

```
async function getData(){
   const res = await axios.get('https://geolocation-db.com/json/')
   console.log(res.data);
   setIP(res.data.IPv4)
}
```

```
React.useEffect(() => {
  //call the function
  getData()

}, [])
```

Then you can pass the IP to your child components, or use "recoil" or any other state management for a global state. You can also send the IP to your C# backend by adding it to your requests.

Edit:

If you want to get the hostname of the machine your Reactjs web application is running, just use the same but instead calling an external API like we did above, just modify your function to this:

```
async function getData(){
   const hostname = window.location.hostname;
   setIP(hostname) // Or change the state name to setHostname
}
```